# Gradle Error compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-location-maps:11.0.2' error(34,13)

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error when I try to add the following dependency:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-location-maps'

to Build.gradle(Module: app)

Then I get the error:

Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-location-maps:11.0.2

However, when I say Install Repository and Sync Project it does not work.
How can I resolve this error?

My Build.Gradle(Module: app)

```
{


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-location-maps:11.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

How can I solve this error ?

Comment: Post your both Gradle Files

Comment: that should be `:play-services-locaion:11.0.2` instead of `play-location-maps:11.0.2`   .

Comment: Solved Jimmy, Thanks !